# Sleep in Spock's Mock waits when run by CompletableFuture

Tags: testing, groovy, spock

When I separately run the `runAsyncWithMock` test, it waits for 3 seconds until the mock's execution is finalised, rather than get terminated like the other 2 tests.

I was not able to figure out why.

It is interesting that:

1. When multiple `Runnables` are executed by `CompletableFuture.runAsync` in a row in the `runAsyncWithMock` test, only the first one waits, the others not.
2. When having multiple duplicated `runAsyncWithMock` tests, each and every of them runs for 3s when the whole specification is executed.
3. When using Class instance rather than a Mock, the test is finalised immediately.

Any idea what I got wrong?

My configuration:

- macOS Mojave 10.14.6
- Spock 1.3-groovy-2.4
- Groovy 2.4.15
- JDK 1.8.0_201

The repo containing the whole Gradle project for reproduction:

https://github.com/lobodpav/CompletableFutureMisbehavingTestInSpock

The problematic test's code:

```
@Stepwise
class SpockCompletableFutureTest extends Specification {
    def runnable = Stub(Runnable) {
        run() >> {
            println "${Date.newInstance()} BEGIN1 in thread ${Thread.currentThread()}"
            sleep(3000)
            println "${Date.newInstance()} END1   in thread ${Thread.currentThread()}"
        }
    }

    def "runAsyncWithMock"() {
        when:
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(runnable)

        then:
        true
    }

    def "runAsyncWithMockAndClosure"() {
        when:
        CompletableFuture.runAsync({ runnable.run() })

        then:
        true
    }

    def "runAsyncWithClass"() {
        when:
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Runnable() {
            void run() {
                println "${Date.newInstance()} BEGIN2 in thread ${Thread.currentThread()}"
                sleep(3000)
                println "${Date.newInstance()} END2   in thread ${Thread.currentThread()}"
            }
        })

        then:
        true
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot confirm that. All 3 tests terminate immediately, test execution even ends before they can print their final messages, most of the time not even the initial messages. If I want to see all messages, I have to do something like: `def future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(runnable); while (!future.done) { sleep 100 }`

Comment: Did you execute only the `runAsyncWithMock` test separately? E.g. not the whole specification?

Comment: Of course I did. I ran all three feature methods separately and the whole test. The result is the same. The only difference from your setup is that I use Spock 1.3-groovy-2.5 and Groovy 2.5.7, but I don't expect that to make any difference. Otherwise I am also on Java 8, OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Hmm, then there must be some changes between our framework versions. or me, the test always runs for 3s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the `synchronized` methods in https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/mock/runtime/MockController.java when a mock is executed it delegates through the `handle` method. The Specification also uses the `synchronized` methods, in this case probably `leaveScope`, and is thus blocked by the sleeping Stub method.

Since this is a thread interleaving problem I guess that additional closure in `runAsyncWithMockAndClosure` moves the execution of the stub method behind the `leaveScope` and thus changes the ordering/blocking.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is also the reason why the `runAsyncWithClass ` test works as expected.

Comment: By the way, why the mock-handling methods need to be synchronized?

Comment: So that the recording of interactions and the scoping does work correctly (not throwing exceptions), when threads are involved.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, just now after writing my last comment I saw a difference:

You use `@Stepwise` (I didn't when I tried at first), an annotation I almost never use because it creates dependencies between feature methods (bad, bad testing practice). While I cannot say why this has the effect described by you only when running the first method, I can tell you that removing the annotation fixes it.

P.S.: With `@Stepwise` you cannot even execute the second or third method separately because the runner will always run the preceding one(s) first, because - well, the specification is said to be executed step-wise. ;-)

---

**Update:** I could briefly reproduce the problem with `@Stepwise`, but after recompilation now it does not happen anymore, neither with or without that annotation.

Comment: I have used @Stepwise only to ensure the `runAsyncWithMock` test is always executed first - this way the first test always takes 3s to complete. Anyway, even if I run the first test separately without @Stepwise, it also runs for 3s.

Comment: Then please publish an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including Maven build (or Gradle as a second choice) on GitHub so as to make the problem reproducible for me.

Comment: Thanks, will do and update the Question with a link.

Comment: The GitHub link is now attached to the question.

Comment: I can reproduce with your sample project when running Gradle, even after upgrading to _org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5_. Please note that I build my own project with Maven. I noticed one funny thing in IntelliJ IDEA: After switching the IDE's Gradle settings to build + run tests in IDEA instead of Gradle, the first time I run the test it runs fast, but after that in every re-run I see the effect of waiting 3 seconds as you describe it. In my own Maven project everything is fine, no matter if I run in Maven or from IDEA.

Comment: I build with Eclipse Groovy compiler, by the way. Maybe that also makes a difference.

Comment: Another thing I noticed: If in your cloned project I set JDK 11 in IntelliJ IDEA project settings and compile + run tests via IDEA, the problem occurs. If I switch to JDK 8, it disappears. So somehow the Java version seems to be relevant, too.

Comment: I am sorry, now it appears in both Java versions. Then sometimes it only appears the first time after a rebuild then then goes away. This is completely flaky. I am running out of ideas. Must be something with forking processes, threads or so. A race condition could also be involved.

Comment: I run the tests by Gradle and Intellij, and the issue appeared mostly consistently. But when you mentioned it, I’ve realised that in a few cases the test completed immediately. It is also related to the Spock Mock. When using a Class in the third test, the test always terminates immediately.